# How to select multiple elements with xPath?

Tags: javascript, object, xpath

I'm using [defiantjs](http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator) to select elements in an object. This is my object:

```
{
 "name": "Retail Sales",
 "weight": 10,
 "length": 6,
 "type": "retailSales",
 "rows": [
  {
     "dealerEvaluationHistoryID": 0,
     "performanceDealerMappingDetailID": 14,
     "month": 1,
     "plan": 0,
     "actual": 0,
     "weight": 0,
     "pelanggaranWilayah": 0
  },
  {
     "dealerEvaluationHistoryID": 0,
     "performanceDealerMappingDetailID": 14,
     "month": 2,
     "plan": 0,
     "actual": 0,
     "weight": 0,
     "pelanggaranWilayah": 0
  },
  {
     "dealerEvaluationHistoryID": 0,
     "performanceDealerMappingDetailID": 14,
     "month": 3,
     "plan": 0,
     "actual": 0,
     "weight": 0,
     "pelanggaranWilayah": 0
  }
 ]
}
```

How do I select all month, plan, actual and weight inside each objects in row[]?
I'd like an output like this:

```
[[1,0,0,0],[2,0,0,0],[3,0,0,0]]
```

I can do `//rows/month` and `//rows/plan` but don't know how to do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` method which applies a **callback** function for every item in the array.

Read more about [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
let obj={
   "name": "Retail Sales",
   "weight": 10,
   "length": 6,
   "type": "retailSales",
   "rows": [
      {
         "dealerEvaluationHistoryID": 0,
         "performanceDealerMappingDetailID": 14,
         "month": 1,
         "plan": 0,
         "actual": 0,
         "weight": 0,
         "pelanggaranWilayah": 0
      },
      {
         "dealerEvaluationHistoryID": 0,
         "performanceDealerMappingDetailID": 14,
         "month": 2,
         "plan": 0,
         "actual": 0,
         "weight": 0,
         "pelanggaranWilayah": 0
      },
      {
         "dealerEvaluationHistoryID": 0,
         "performanceDealerMappingDetailID": 14,
         "month": 3,
         "plan": 0,
         "actual": 0,
         "weight": 0,
         "pelanggaranWilayah": 0
      }
   ]
}
let array=obj.rows.map(function(row){
  return [row.month,row.plan,row.actual,row.weight];
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Will accept this as the answer when the timer's up :)